# Decompilation and Protection of Mkbundled CLI Image of .NET Executable

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have complied a .net executable(GTK Based UI) using mkbundle by statically including mono runtime using

```
mkbundle --static hello.exe -o --deps hello
```

I got a CLI Image.Is this CLI Image Native Code like a Complied C Program?Can it be disassembled easily like any other normal .NET Executable? If yes is there a way to make decompilation Hard? Is Obfuscation before mkbundling an option? and Can i do AOT(Ahead of Time) Compilation? Please throw some light on this.

Comment: I checked some mkbundle generated executables and I found the dlls and exes in it, so yes it can be disassembled but it's a little bit harder to find the start and ends of dlls and exes in the bundled file.

Comment: @robot9706 Thanks.But can the source code be easily read like a normal .net executable.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that those exes and dlls are .NET assemblies, so it's easy to decompile them.

Comment: @robot9706 Did you use the static flag?

Comment: Even if I use that flag I can find the .NET exes and dlls in the bundled executable.

Comment: @robot9706 okay..But we are compiling only one exe right? Where do you think the other executables are coming from?

Comment: If you enable "--deps" the bundled executable will contain your application exe, mscorlib and other dlls which are required to run the app. When I commented ".NET exes and dlls" I was talking in general.